# Sound output starts delayed. Cant force sampling rate on boot

Tags: nvidia, sound, pulseaudio, alsa, hdmi

Whenever the PC boots and I start playing some audio, HDMI audio starts playing after 3 seconds. Before playing any audio file, if I run this command: `pacmd list-sinks | grep sample`, I get this output:

> sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
> sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz

After playing some files and experiencing the 3-second delay, if I rerun the same command, I see this output:

> sample spec: s16le 2ch 48000Hz
> sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz

Therefore, I assume the delay is due to changing the audio sample rate from 44100Hz to 48000Hz. In order to force 48000Hz on boot, in the file **/etc/pulse/daemon.conf**  I updated the values to:
`; default-sample-format = s16le ; default-sample-rate = 48000 ; alternate-sample-rate = 48000`

Also in files **/etc/pulse/default.pa** and **/etc/pulse/system.pa** have commented out `load-module module-suspend-on-idle`.

However, on boot, the sample rate remains at 44100Hz for both cases. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hi - please add the Ubuntu version that you are using so others can help as best as possible.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look above, you will see `Default values are commented out.  Use either ; or # for`. Remove the `;` to uncomment the lines:

```
default-sample-format = s16le
default-sample-rate = 48000
alternate-sample-rate = 48000
```

Comment: Audio is distorted on boot. I added `pulseaudio -k` in _Startup Applications Preferences_  App to solve the distortion issue

Comment: At least you have your sampling rate working like you wanted. If you want to fix the distortion, which is not a simple thing to fix, you should post a new question, and include sound hardware information like `lspci ; aplay -l`